# openpyxl adding specific row to the list

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm searching for the rows that match my criteria, if row matches I add row's index to a list `match`.
After that I need to add data of the rows that matched into a list.

I tried this

```
for i in match:
    for j in range(1,ws.max_column+1):
        a1 = ws.cell(row = i, column = j)
        result.append(a1.value)
```

but it adds them as an elements:

```
['row 1',1,'row 3',3]
```

Is there a way to get the row's data in a double list like this: `[['row 1',1],['row 3',3]]`

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in match:
    for j in range(1,ws.max_column+1):
        l = []
        a1 = ws.cell(row = i, column = j)
        l.append(a1.value)
        result.append(l)
```

Initialize a `list` in your loop so you have a list as entry in your `result`

Edit: your wb must be in `data_only = True` for example `wb = load_workbook("file.xlsx", data_only=True)`